# How to find the best array match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have quiz1, quiz2 and quiz3, and I want to recommend a quiz to the user , either quiz1 or quiz2 based on the tags from quiz3 without taking every document in the collection and work on them on the application level.

```
Quiz_1 = {                                                  
    _id:"...",                                                  
    tags:["life-style","personality","sports","soccer"]         
}; 

Quiz_2 = {
    _id:"...",
    tags:["IQ","inteligence","science","maths"]
};

Quiz_3 = {
    _id:"...",                                                  
    tags:["life-style","maths","inteligence","school"]        
};
```

The best match here is quiz_2, because quiz_3 matches quiz_2 with 2 tags and matches quiz_1 with only 1 tag. (more tag matches equals a better match) How do I do that using mongoose?

Explanation:

I have a collection named "quizzes" and i want mongodb to return the second document when I enter (tags:["life-style","maths","inteligence","school"])

```
quizzes:
[
  {
    _id:...,
    tags:["life-style","personality","sports","soccer"]]
  },
  {
   _id:"...",
   tags:["IQ","inteligence","science","maths"]
  },
  {
   _id:"...",
   tags:["life-style","maths","inteligence","school"]  
  }
]
```

Comment: Obviously? Why? Do you think you could explain why?

Comment: because quiz_3 matches quiz_2 with 2 tags and matches quiz_1 with only 1 tag

Comment: So you are looking for the "largest intersection of sets" for each term. I can't see how that applies to the "User" though. Is the user supposed to have their own list of terms to intersect? Please keep explaining. In the question of course. It's still not as clear as you seem to think.

Comment: Finally we got an explanation. Don't use tag names in question titles when asking here. That's why I removed it.

Comment: Thanks, Neil! You're the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to get the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) of the comparison array and the `"tags"` array in the document. Then you [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to get the largest "size" on top, and finally [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to one result:

```
var compare = ["life-style","maths","inteligence","school"];

Quizzes.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "tags": { "$in": compare } } },
  { "$project": {
    "size": {
      "$size": {
        "$setIntersection": [ compare, "$tags" ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "size": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 1 }
 ])
```

You speed it up by only examining documents that actually have at least one match by using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).